# Patch a contrib module with a patch that contains new files

Tags: 8

How do I patch the [recaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module with the [invisible recaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/node/2852269) patch using drush make? I patch modules all the time in project.make.yml with yml that looks just like this:

```
...
# Recaptcha 8.x-2.2 - 2016-07-30
recaptcha:
  subdir: contrib
  version: '2.2'
  patch:
    # Integrate Invisible reCAPTCHA option from Google
    - 'https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/recaptcha-invisible-option-2852269-56.patch'
...
```

What's different with the invisible recaptcha patch is the patch contains two new files.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you consider switching to composer and composer-patches. I don't think drush make is still actively maintained?

Quick google search pointed me to http://www.anexusit.com/blog/how-to-apply-patches-drupal-8-composer for example. That works fine, also for patches that add new files. The only case where that is a problem is core, due to different path structures in drupal/core and then it doesn't apply it correctly.

Comment: We use composer as well even though our composer.json is not stable because we use grunt-drupal-tasks for our build. 

I changed the `composer require` to:

`composer require drupal/captcha drupal/recaptcha:2.x-dev`

and the patch was applied successfully during the build process.

But now I'm on the dev version of the module.